# How to prevent large deviation on HERE way-point plot?

Tags: here-api

I have journeys with up to 50 way-points that I'd like to plot using the HERE API, one journey per map.  The maps look great in general, but in some cases the route deviates wildly from the the arc of the journey, for a few points, before resuming.

As an example, here is a [HERE API map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOorR.png), and a non-snap-to-route map from [GPS Visualizer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gynyo.png), both from the same data.  You can see the HERE route hugs the main roads but has a diversion or two, whereas the other plots point-to-point naively and has no diversion.  The raw request (sans app-key and the last few way-points) is [here](https://image.maps.api.here.com/mia/1.6/routing?app_id=XXXXXXX&app_code=XXXXXXX&f=0&t=0&nocp&z=14&ppi=320&w=600&h=600&lc=1652B4&lw=6&waypoint0=51.509391784668,-0.437685996294022&waypoint1=51.509449005127,-0.441464513540268&waypoint2=51.5088806152344,-0.443244993686676&waypoint3=51.5105667114258,-0.446897000074387&waypoint4=51.5129203796387,-0.450538665056229&waypoint5=51.5195007324219,-0.451829165220261&waypoint6=51.5293502807617,-0.453992158174515&waypoint7=51.5342102050781,-0.456675678491592&waypoint8=51.5351791381836,-0.461071670055389&waypoint9=51.5351829528809,-0.461465328931808&waypoint10=51.5368995666504,-0.460058003664017&waypoint11=51.539421081543,-0.460379332304001&waypoint12=51.5424308776855,-0.462484985589981&waypoint13=51.5460052490234,-0.461131155490875&waypoint14=51.5481910705566,-0.462916821241379&waypoint15=51.5505714416504,-0.457452833652496&waypoint16=51.5515975952148,-0.454072654247284&waypoint17=51.5550498962402,-0.457684010267258&waypoint18=51.5595397949219,-0.476642996072769&waypoint19=51.5612449645996,-0.496631652116776&waypoint20=51.5614547729492,-0.510428309440613&waypoint21=51.5665740966797,-0.534164845943451&waypoint22=51.576488494873,-0.536092162132263&waypoint23=51.5885696411133,-0.533756673336029&waypoint24=51.5973777770996,-0.531651854515076&waypoint25=51.6044540405273,-0.529385328292847&waypoint26=51.6123428344727,-0.527255654335022&waypoint27=51.6330757141113,-0.515904307365417&waypoint28=51.6389312744141,-0.508256852626801&waypoint29=51.6429786682129,-0.502533972263336&waypoint30=51.6524925231934,-0.497588157653809&waypoint31=51.6613998413086,-0.49453467130661&waypoint32=51.6731452941895,-0.470016002655029&waypoint33=51.6805953979492,-0.453563988208771&waypoint34=51.6835174560547,-0.431829839944839&waypoint35=51.6843147277832,-0.42891851067543&waypoint36=51.6839714050293,-0.408509343862534&waypoint37=51.6835823059082,-0.406337320804596&waypoint38=51.6833763122559,-0.405024319887161&waypoint39=51.6830024719238,-0.402583003044128&waypoint40=51.6819610595703,-0.396028161048889&waypoint41=51.6808280944824,-0.388587176799774&waypoint42=51.6765060424805,-0.379159331321716&waypoint43=51.6758499145508,-0.378113180398941&waypoint44=51.6669158935547,-0.364176839590073&waypoint45=51.6632385253906,-0.358539670705795&waypoint46=51.6582260131836,-0.351045846939087)

The guess is that GPS drift has moved the way-point slightly off the main road and onto a minor road and the routing algorithm taking a necessary diversion to get back to the next point.

Please, would anyone be able to suggest an approach, or parameters I can tweak, to minimise the number or severity of the deviations?

Many thanks!
Nikki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Map Image Routing API calculates the route based on the provided waypoints. So the waypoints you provide have direct influence on the route calculated without much optimisation. It may be necessary to first compute the most probable route given your GPX trace (waypoints) using the  [Fleet Telematics Route Matching API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/what-is.html) before drawing the response (the matched/snapped route) on the map.